# Picturing a normal mode of vibration of the monoatomic lattice in 1D that is either in-phase nor completely out-of-phase

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, vibrations, phonons, normal-modes

For a monoatomic lattice of $N$ atoms in **one-dimension**, the ratio of the displacements of two consecutive atoms at the $(n+1)$th and the $n$th site is given by $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=e^{ika}$$ where this relation is *independent* of the site label $n$. With periodic boundary conditions, the gap between two consecutive $k$-values is, $\Delta k=2\pi/Na$. Thus, the allowed number of $k$-values in the first Brillouin zone is $N$, and there are $N$ distinct normal modes.

Consider the value of $k=\pi/a$ such that  $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=e^{i\pi}=-1,$$ which means that the consecutive atoms at each site are moving with equal and opposite displacements  (i.e., in completely out-of-phase). This motion is easy to picture or draw in 1D.

Now, consider a value of $k$ such that $e^{ika}$ is a complex (in particular, a case where $e^{ika}\neq \pm 1$). Here, the displacements at consecutive sites are still equal in magnitude, $|u_{n+1}|=|u_n|$ but have a phase difference. How do you **picture** or **visualize** such a mode of vibration?

Comment: You have a problem if $e^{ika}\neq \pm 1$ as $u_{\rm n\pm ?}$ tends towards infinity as you move in one direction and tends towards zero as you move in the other.

Comment: @Farcher Not sure I understand. $e^{ika}$ can take values other than $\pm 1$. These values are pure phases and thus, have unit magnitude.

Comment: Ignore my comment as I misread your question.  Does this gif, [1D normal modes](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1D_normal_modes.gif), help answer your question. It came form the Wikipedia article [Phonon - One dimensional lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#One-dimensional_lattice)

Comment: Even better visual representation? [1-d chain of atoms](http://lampz.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss1/phonons/1d/1dphonons.php)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Let me try to express it in words. When $e^{ika}=\pm 1$, two consecutive atoms move in the same or opposite direction and attain maximum simultaneously. For complex values of $e^{ika}$, they do not attain their maximum simultaneously. Is this correct? If not, could you please express it in words and post it as an answer?

Comment: As shown in the simulations your example has the highest frequency and the largest $k$ value.  Other modes have a lower frequency and there is a variation in phase between adjacent atoms..